# How to Disable Green and Magenta Faces?

Tags: sculpting, faces

All I did was fixed my model by removing a certain face and by filling it with a new face. When I enter sculpting mode, these green and magenta faces are now in my model. How do I remove this? I tried to delete the faces and refill it again, I even restarted blender, but it's still there.

[image]

Comment: Probably check Face Sets https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/editing/face_sets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vklidu says, these are Faces Sets (there are used as sort of masks in *Sculpt* mode):

[image]

To remove them go into the *Face Sets panel > Initialize Face Sets > By Loose Parts*:

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! :D